# Disable Calendar Entries in Exchange 2003 IMAP Folders

Tags: exchange, imap

When logging in to Exchange 2003 with a standard IMAP Client (not outlook, but thunderbird or even telnet), i am seeing a bunch of folders that are not mail folders:

```
. list "" "*"
* LIST (\HasNoChildren) "/" Drafts
* LIST (\HasNoChildren) "/" Notes
* LIST (\HasChildren) "/" Tasks
* LIST (\HasNoChildren) "/" "Junk E-mail"
* LIST (\HasNoChildren) "/" Journal
* LIST (\HasNoChildren) "/" Tasks/sjakie!
* LIST (\HasNoChildren) "/" INBOX/000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001111011111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111011111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111011111111111
* LIST (\HasChildren) "/" "Sent Items"
* LIST (\HasNoChildren) "/" "Sent Items/Junk E-mail"
* LIST (\HasNoChildren) "/" Outbox
* LIST (\HasNoChildren) "/" Contacts
* LIST (\HasNoChildren) "/" Calendar
* LIST (\HasNoChildren) "/" "Deleted Items"
* LIST (\HasChildren) "/" INBOX
* LIST (\Noselect) "/" "Public Folders/"
```

There are a bunch of other folders (contacts, calendars, etc.).

Is there a way to tell Exchange to stop showing me those items in IMAP?